# SQL errors on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-sql

Error:

```
code: 'ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP', errno: 1055,
code: 'ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS', errno: 1140
```

Different error depending on some changes I tried to avoid the errors.
The query that breaks in my Node.js:

```
'SELECT e.eventName, e.eventDesc, COUNT(ua.eventID) AS cnt '
            + 'FROM charitydb.events AS e, charitydb.user_activity AS ua '
            + 'WHERE  e.eventID = ua.eventID '
            + 'GROUP BY e.eventName '
            + 'ORDER BY cnt DESC'
```

**Cannot disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY since there are no super privileges on GCP.**

Comment: you need to add `e.eventDesc` in your group by

Answer (score 0):

As Guillaume suggested on the comment, this mode is enabled by default since MySQL 5.7.5 ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)), and, as GCP doesn't allow users to have [SUPER privileges](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#superuser_restrictions) for being a managed service, you will need to conduct a full GROUP clause with all the selected fields.

So, your fixed code would be:

```sql
'SELECT e.eventName, e.eventDesc, COUNT(ua.eventID) AS cnt '
            + 'FROM charitydb.events AS e, charitydb.user_activity AS ua '
            + 'WHERE  e.eventID = ua.eventID '
            + 'GROUP BY e.eventName, e.eventDesc '
            + 'ORDER BY cnt DESC'
```

More information about how MySQL handles groups [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).